# Azure Functions not being recognised when in folder

Tags: python, azure-functions

I'm adding a new Azure function to an existing project, for it to be picked up and created by the pipeline, it needs to be inside the folder structure, but when it is, it's not being picked up as a working function.

The current folder structure is

```
   - chat
     - __init__
   - ask
     - __init__
     - host.json
   - translate
     - __init__
     - host.json
     - functions
         - __init__
         - getBlob
         - getVars
         - readBlob
- host.json
- local.settings.json
- requirements.txt
```

I'd assumed it had something to do with the incorrect file structuring, but if I open translate for example as a folder on its own and run func init to add the other packages, it still isn't picked up as an Azure function.

These are V1 functions, running on Python 3.10.

This is the contents of host.json

```
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  }
}
```

Currently, when I try to run locally I get this output in the console:
[image]

Any ideas for how to fix this would be great!

Comment: Add `local.settings.json` in translate folder. And run the function via `translate` folder.

Comment: As in open the folder on it's own and run from there?

Comment: You can navigate to translate folder in terminal and run `func start`.

Comment: That makes sense! I'm getting the same problem trying to hit the function from the deployed version, seemingly, would moving the local settings also resolve this?

Comment: To deploy the function, you should have the requirements.txt file as well in the function folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments:

To run the function which is in a different folder:

1. you should add `local.settings.json` in that particular folder
   (or)
2. Move out the function file to the root folder where you have `host.json` and `local.settings.json`.

I have created a python Azure function as below:

**Project Structure:**

```
|   host.json
|   local.settings.json
|   requirements.txt
+---.vscode
|
+---app
|   |   host.json
|   \---HttpTrigger
|       |   function.json
|       |   host.json
|       |   __init__.py
+---env
|
\---HttpTrigger1
        function.json
        sample.dat
        __init__.py
```

I was facing the same issue with the above project structure.

- **To resolve this, I have added `local.settings.json` to `app` folder.**

```
|   host.json
|   local.settings.json
|   requirements.txt
+---.vscode
|
+---app
|   |   host.json
|   |   local.settings.json
|   \---HttpTrigger
|       |   function.json
|       |   host.json
|       |   __init__.py
```

To run the function, navigate to the folder where the function trigger is available and run the function.

- I am able to run the function inside `app` folder with the command:

[image]